# accepting Epd1in54 as argument in a Function

Tags: rust, arduino

From an Arduino Micro (Atmega 328P) I want to control a small e-paper display, the Waveshare [Epd1in54](https://docs.rs/epd-waveshare/latest/epd_waveshare/epd1in54/struct.Epd1in54.html) in Rust. To use it with [embedded-graphics](https://docs.rs/embedded-graphics/latest/embedded_graphics/), I need to implement [DrawTarget](https://docs.rs/embedded-graphics-core/latest/embedded_graphics_core/draw_target/trait.DrawTarget.html) for a display struct, which has a field holding the Epd1in54 variable.

I can use the functions of It works here:

```rust
fn update_display(epd: &dyn WaveshareDisplay<SPI, Output, Input, Output, Output, [Delay](), DisplayColor = Color>) {}
```

But this accepts any epd display, therefore the size is not known at compile time. (and because of that I can’t implement [DrawTarget](https://docs.rs/embedded-graphics-core/latest/embedded_graphics_core/draw_target/trait.DrawTarget.html) for a struct with the display in a field.

Theoretically

```
fn update_display(epd: &Epd1in54<SPI, Output, Input, Output, Output, Delay>) {}
```

should work but at least in auto completions the epd functions don’t show up

Relevant imports:

```
use avr_device::atmega328p::SPI;
use epd_waveshare::{
    epd1in54::Epd1in54,
    prelude::*
};
use arduino_hal::{
    port::mode::{
        Input,
        Output
    },
    Delay
};
```

Comment: It appears that you have inserted markdown links in your code snippets, could you please remove those? Besides, could you add a little more details, it's not clear (to me) what your problem is exactly. Does the function with `Epd1in54` throw an error during compilation, or is it just your editor which doesn't autocomplete that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: The key was to pretend a functions from the display existed on the variable and let the compiler complain about the missing traits.

The problem was that `SPI`, `Output` and `Input` didn’t fulfill the trait bounds. My guess is because `WaveshareDisplay` is dynamic, the problem didn’t appear at compile time.

The final display type now is:

```rust
type Display = Epd1in54<Spi, Pin<Output>, Pin<Input>, Pin<Output>, Pin<Output>, Delay>;
```